# How to use Java Script variable inside ruby code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to use javascript variable inside ruby code. I tried with the following code but its not working.

```
 <script>
 var total=100
 <%@final_amount + = total%>
 </script>
```

It's throwing error because total is a java script variable. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to understand how the client-server model works first. Ruby is server-side, JS is client-side. Ruby is executed before JavaScript.

Comment: @elclanrs so can't we do that?

Comment: Not the way you think. You can generate JavaScript in Ruby. You can communicate between the client and server using AJAX and JSON. The server and the client are isolated.

Comment: how to do that? please post as an answer. @elclanrs

Comment: Before downvoting put the reason as comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's important for you to understand that your Ruby stuff is happening on the server-side and the Javascript is for the client-side. I'm not sure why you would do that in a script. I imagine you could just do that outright in your erb file in Ruby. Note that your Javascript won't know what that means.

Ruby will run, (I'm not sure if Ruby works within the script tags or they purposely don't allow that. I imagine they purposely don't allow that, so that alone will trigger an error), but it won't know what `total` is. It only understands Ruby. So, when you get to the client-side, you won't have ruby anymore. You'll have the html that was compiled from that Ruby. In your script, you'll have `var total = 100;` but you won't have that ruby script in there. It'll have been compiled to html. This is assuming erb files even allow that within scripts, which I'm not sure they do.